# Parsing an equation

Tags: c

I'd like to ask if someone could help me out with my problem.

I have to parse an arbitrary equation into variables and numbers.

Equation will be in form `"y1 + y2 + ... + y10"`.

Sample: `"y1 + 2 y2 + 3y3 + y3 + 3 + 5   +   10 = y4 + 4"`

There can be random number of spaces. "y1" is not 1*y. It is y with index 1.

I was thinking about using `strchar(string," ")` and parse it that way, but it can be without spaces, so maybe reading char after char, but then I don't have idea how to do equation like `"3    y2"`, maybe if I think about taking first char, then read next chars `while(char == " ")` and then take that next char and look if it is variable or "+". I don't need source code for it, I'm ok with hint.

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: You could use a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_machine).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you perform a Google search for "C parsing library". Here is one that looks interesting:

http://warp.povusers.org/FunctionParser/

Hmm, that one is actually C++... If you really want C, there are others.

You are not the first person to have this problem, and there are libraries to solve it.

You could also use Flex and Bison. Here is a tutorial.

http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/